# Как вывести в строку знак : /

Tags: c++, qt

В общем пытаюсь сделать отчет и в отчете должны быть сырые данные `*.bin` битники (точнее где они лежат ) . Но выходной фаил `*.txt` обрабатывает *LATEX*   и приводит к формату `.rtf` . 
Проблема заключается что битники лежат в файле *MA_Check* (название изменить нельзя) , и чтобы латех отобразил `_` надо ввести `/_` но в Qt это команда "строка коментов" . Что делать как быть ????

```
char str[] = "Hello/World/";
size_t count = std::strlen(str);



int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<count; ++i)
{
    if(str[i] == 'l')
    {
        count = count+1;
    }
    j = j+1;
    qDebug() <<j;
}
qDebug() <<"str :" <<str ;
qDebug() <<"j" << j;

char str1[88] ;
int t =0;
for (int i =0; i<j; ++i)
{

    if(str[i] == '/')
    {
        str1[t] = '/';
        t = t+1;
        str1[t] = '/';

    }
    else
    {
       str1[t] = str[i];

    }
    //        qDebug() <<"i :" << i;
    //        qDebug() <<"t :" << t;
    t= t+1;
    if(str[i] == '_')
    {
        str1[t] = '\';
        t = t+1;
        str1[t] = '/';

    }
    else
    {
       str1[t] = str[i];
    }

}
qDebug() <<"str :" <<str ;
qDebug() <<"str1 :" << str1;

ui->setupUi(this);
```

Comment: первым делом - у вас в коде строка str1[t] = '\'; неверна, этот слеш используется для ввода спец символов. чтобы ввести именно его, нужно написать str1[t] = '\\';

Comment: К чему все эти манипуляции с символами? Если уж используете `Qt`, так пользуйтесь функционалом `QString`: `QString::replace(const QString& before, const QString& after)`.

Comment: А вообще, не очень понятно что вам надо. Приведите пример двух строк: строка, которую вы имеете, и строка, которую вам надо получить.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что у вас входной файл? Чем он обрабатывается сначала и что получается? Чем он обрабатывается потом, и что получается. Опишите проблему по шагам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ошибка в этом месте:

```
if(str[i] == '_')
{
    str1[t] = '\';  // ошибка здесь
    t = t+1;
    str1[t] = '/';  // здесь правильно

}
```

В Си и Си++ символ `\` внутри строковых и символьных литералов играет роль экранирующего. Это означает что следующий за ним символ воспринимается компилятором либо как [символ форматирования](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape), либо если это замыкающий символ литерала (`"` для строковых и `'` для символьных) как продолжение этого литерала. Во втором случае это нужно если необходимо в строке поместить кавычку `"`, например:

```
const char * str = "it is \"quoted\" string"; // it is "quoted" string
```

То же самое если вам нужен символ `'` char'у присвоить:

```
char quote = '\''; // quote = '
```

Если вам нужен сам символ `\` то его тоже надо экранировать, то есть в литерале нужно писать `\\`:

```
const char * path = "C:\\Program Files\\"; //  C:\Program Files\
char slash = '\\'; // shash = \
```

У вас же происходит следующее:  в сроке `str1[t] = '\';` вы забыли заэкранировать обратный слеш и компилятор считает весь последующий код продолжением литерала который вы хотите присвоить `str1[t]`.

Правильно будет так:

```
if(str[i] == '_')
{
    str1[t] = '\\';  // ок
    t = t+1;
    str1[t] = '/';  //  ок

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как мне кажется, всё что нужно знать в данном случае, это то, что символ `\` (обратная косая черта) используется как экранирующий символ. Об этом говорится в любом учебнике по C/C++. Т.о. везде (кроме сырых строк c++11), где требуется одиночным символ `\` нужно писать `\\`.

Например, в строке, указывающей путь: `const char* path = "C:\\Folder\\file.cpp";` или в одиночном символе `char ch = '\\';`.

При этом символ `/` (косая черта) экранировать не нужно вовсе.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы LaTeX отобразил MA_Check, достаточно ввести

`\begin{verbatim}MA_Check\end{verbatim}`

Если очень нужен шрифт (Roman), поможет следующая конструкция:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\begin{document}
\begin{alltt}
\rmfamily
MA_Check
\end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

Но закрывать окружение `alltt` получится только в конце документа. И я не проверял её взаимодействие с русификатором `babel`

Comment: Ну, verbatim отобразит текст ещё и моноширинным шрифтом, ЕМНИП.

Comment: Само собой, мы же сами отказались от какой-либо вёрстки.